# Arrays and IF-tags

Tags: php, arrays, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to have a PHP webpage saying just a simple:

```
"Hi, today its ___day have a nice week!"

"Hi, today its ___day have a nice weekend!".
```

The code I have atm is (sorry for the random swedish at some points):

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'english');
$day = strftime('%A', time());
$week=array("monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday","sunday");
if ($day<"saturday");
{
    echo "Idag är det " . $day . "Ha en trevlig vardag!";
}
else if ($day>"friday");
{
    echo "Idag är det " . $day . "Ha en trevlig helg!";
}
else ($day="sunday");
{
    echo "Idag är det " . $day . "Ha en trevlig vecka!";
}
```

Comment: if you echo $day, what does it produce?

Comment: Also, i'm pretty sure `>` and `<` are in reference to integers? So not sure you can check if a string is less than or more than another string? You'd want to be using `==` or `!=` i think

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help  It should help you formatting your post.  When pasting in code, select it and click the `{}` button on the toolbar to put it in a "code block".  I fixed this post for you :-)

Comment: When I echo $day i get an error: 
"Error: [4] syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) occurred on line 10"
But lets say for instance i remove the else tags, it works and it writes out the current day..

And sorry, i will do that, definetly!

Comment: @PontusLundh: Where did you put `echo $day;`?  Did you add a `;` at the end?

Comment: When i Use just the "echo $day" it works and it says the current day..

But I want it to say like:
echo "Today its" . $day . "Have a nice week/weekend.

Comment: I don't think `$day<"saturday"` does what you think it does.

Comment: It probably doesnt :( im just testing everything. But It feels like im overthinking it, super much.
Is ther anyway to put the weekdays into arrays, then use the arrays  within if and if else tags?

Comment: I removed it, and keep getting the same message on the same line tho..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to build an array here to work with. Just use DateTime object.  You should be able to greatly simplify this:

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
// get day of week string
$message = "Idag är det " . $datetime->format('l');
// get day of week number. gives day number 1 (Monday) - 7 (Sunday)
$day_of_week_number = (int)$datetime->format('N');
switch ($day_of_week_number) {
    case 7:
        $message .= ' Ha en trevlig vecka!';
        break;
    case 6:
        $message .= ' Ha en trevlig helg!';
        break;
    default:
        $message .= ' Ha en trevlig vardag!';
        break;
}
echo $message;
```

Comment: That worked great. But for me just reading that code i understand nada.. hah.
Is it actually possible to do it with using the same code as I "kinda" had but with arrays?

Comment: @PontusLundh Why make an array when it is not needed? PHP already has built-in capability to work with dates, including the extremely useful DateTime class I use in my example.  This allows you to simply instantiate an object for the current date and time, then format it in different ways. Here is a list of all supported formatting characters - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php As you can see the options there are very robust.

Comment: @PontusLundh Here the first line of code instantiates the DateTime object.  The next two lines get the current date in two different formats (full day of week text and day of week number).  The switch statement then compares the value for day of week number against your options in order to complete the sentence.

Comment: Thanks, I'm saving this and i'll read up more on that webpage just so I understand every single letter of it! :D And I'll try to play aronud with it as much as possible, if it is possible.
I appreciate the fast respond!

If I could, i would upvote!

Comment: Dont know if you're still here, PRobably a retarded question.. But the "Cases" Im guessing thats the Days.. 1-7 ? right? Case 6 - Saturday, Case 7 - Sunday? Or am i completely out of it..

Comment: @PontusLundh That is correct.  You could just as easily do cases around the day of week, but I figured I would show you the use of the number, so if you ever needed to do something like `if($day_of_week_number > 2) { ... }` you would a more reliable (sortable) way than using day names.